# Is writing a library with a dependency on Groovy a good idea?

Tags: java, maven, groovy, gradle

I am writing a Java library right now that I publish as a Maven artifact and use in a different Java/Groovy project. I was wondering whether in general it is a good idea to write a library that depends on a certain version of Groovy (e.g. has a dependency on `groovy-all-2.x.y`).
The discomfort of just using Java in the library would not be too bad.

What do you think?
Should I better use a generous version range for the Groovy dependency? Should I rather write a plain Java library?

Comment: I've never had a good experience with libraries declaring a dependency range.  Do you use any Groovy features (Closures, metaClass, etc) in your library, or is it just written in Groovy?

Comment: It is just written in Groovy. So migration to Java should not be too hard. Adding some getters, setters, adding some semicolons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it depends on how you want it to be used.

1. If it's not a utility and you don't think other projects will use it, then do whatever you want.
2. If it's a utility designed to be used in testing, I don't think a groovy dependency on the test classpath is too bad. I'm sure some projects would still avoid your utility because of the groovy dependency.
3. If it's a general utility that you want people to use everywhere, then I'd say a groovy dependency is definately a bad idea. I certainly wouldn't use it and I'm sure many others would avoid for the same reason.

If you want maximum adoption of your utility, keep the dependencies as few as possible. Groovy is a huge, bloated dependency that many projects will avoid.

Comment: Nice answer, for an example `HTTPBuilder` changed their groovy dependency scope from `compile` to `runtime` to avoid conflicts.

Comment: it is most likely case 3, though it will only be used company internally by a few other projects. But Groovy versions might still clash...

Comment: You'd typically make this a `provided` dependency and leave it up to the consumer to choose the Groovy version. Note that major Groovy versions aren't guaranteed to be backwards-compatible, but minor versions are. Instead of `groovy-all`, you could use specific dependencies such as `groovy-core`, `groovy-sql`, etc.

Comment: @jack_kerouac I guess there's a case 4 then which is "It's a utility that will only be used in groovy projects". In this case, I don't see a problem adding `groovy-all` as a dependency. Projects using your utility can override the version by specifying `groovy-all` in their own poms because of the "nearest definition wins" strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the intended use of this library. If you only plan on using it yourself and are perfectly fine with the groovy dependency as it is then leave it that way. If the library is meant to be used by others than the easiest thing for them might be to write it all in Java, since then there is less that can go wrong when trying to use the library. It really comes down to if the work required to switch it to Java is worth the benefit to you of having it all in Java.